# Increase RAM capacity

Tags: memory

I have an old Dimension XPS T600 PC running Windows XP at the moment. It is pretty old and I have a newer computer for doing everyday tasks so I thought I would turn my old PC into a web server and maybe a server for some other things. I thought I would probably have to upgrade its RAM and maybe a few other things before I did this. If I were to turn it into a server I would probably install Ubuntu Server to host. I saw, after looking online, that the maximum amount of RAM for this computer would be 768 MB. This amount would not be enough for what I would want to be able to do. What I would like to know is if it is possible to somehow add more RAM into my computer. There are three sockets for memory built in to the computer and each socket can hold a maximum of 256 MB. I was wondering if the operating system that the machine was running would change the maximum capacity of the RAM that can be installed in each socket. I was also wondering if it is possible to add in more sockets of memory with 256 MB of RAM each if that is all that the computer can recognize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were it possible to use larger sticks of ram, your chipset would need to support the increased amount of ram, and have a bios that supports it.Considering its a very old system made by a big manufacturer, this is somewhat unlikely. The system also only seems to support [pc100 ram](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/9174-2-dimension-t600-memory), which needs to be taken into account.

You cannot in general add more ram slots.

However, 256 mb of ram is plenty for a personal server, and the maximum 768 mb is plenty for most things. You could also set up a healthy amount of swap space should it be needed. My own personal server system rarely goes over 200 mb of ram used. In addition, being a rather old system, you might find the processor a bottle neck more than ram.

Comment: So adding more ports is out of the question? And it is extremely unlikely for the BIOS to support anything higher than 256 in each bracket? Any other options at all? Thanks

Comment: Well, while its an old system, its probably powerful enough for experimentation - might even be able to run a GUI on it, though text only is a better idea. Honestly, if there's bottlenecks the sensible option would be to replace it with a cheap low end system of a newer vintage since there's *multiple* points of failure of things that arn't cost effective to replace without salvaging them. it uses ram a generation or two old, a processor thats about ten generations old... IDE... and so on. I was using an older system (a PIII 450) for years as a personal web server